# How to tell Pandas read_table a column has numerical values

Tags: python, pandas

This question must have been asked before or is moot. However I can't find the answer. Pandas `read_table` by default takes all the data (cells) as strings. How to tell it a given column (or all of them) have numerical values?

Comment: Set the `dtype=` parameter when calling `read-table()`

Comment: `pd.read_table(infile, dtype={'column1':'int64', 'column2':'np.float32',...)` or `df.astype(int)`

Answer (score 2):

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_table.html

pandas.read_table() has a dtype= param, where you can pass a dict of {column_name: dtype_you_want_for_column}